# Is there any way to find out how many intervals greater than x exist in a list of values?

Tags: functions, applications

I'm not a professional mathematics, but I have a problem of applied mathematics. Beforehand, I apologize for not using more technical terms. I hope I can be as clear as possible:

Given the following values: 8, 9, 10 and 20.

How many times I have an interval greater or equal then 6?

The answer is 1, because between 10 and 20 we have an interval of 10.

In this other list: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 the answer is 0.

And, finally, in this list: 3, 10 and 20 the answer is 3.

Is there a function or way to figure this anwser using math?

Thank to all

Comment: Are you asking about what technology you might use to do this and how?

Comment: I think this is about as mathematical as selecting the fruits from a list of grocery shoppings. You have to just enumerate (assuming your values do not originate from some mathematical source).

Comment: You should use **difference** because normally **interval** has another meaning. But there is another problem: In your first example not only $20-10 \ge 6$ but also 
$20-8\ge6$ etc. So please clarify what you mean.

Comment: @gammatester, You're right, then I believe not be possible to resolve the issue that way. My real problem is that I need to find out how often a certain person visited a place, considering that a new visit means at least six hours of absence.

Comment: @gammatester I think that a term used for the OP problem is **gap**, see for example the appendix of LEE, D. T.; WU, Ying-Fung. Geometric complexity of some location problems. *Algorithmica*, 1986, 1.1-4: 193-211.

Answer (score 2):

You have a set of $n$ numbers $A = \{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \}$, where we assume that those numbers are sorted: $x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_n$.

You can form intervals $[x_i, x_j]$ for $i < j$, with length $x_{ij} = x_j - x_i$.

If one arranges the $x_{ij}$ as a $n\times n$ matrix, these are the elements above the diagonal. There are $N = \frac{(n-1) n}{2}$ of such intervals.

You could formulate your query as
$$
m = \sum_{\overset{i < j}{x_{ij} \ge 6}} 1 = \text{card}\{ x_{ij} \mid i<j \wedge x_{ij} \ge 6 \}
$$

The question how to organize a large set of numbers such that certain queries can be performed efficiently is subject to computer science, in particular data structures.

**Example:**

Set of given numbers:
$$
A = \{ 1, 3, 10, 22 \} 
$$
Matrix of differences $x_{ij}$:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
  0 & \color{red} 2 & \color{green} 9 & \color{green}{21} \\
 -2 &   0 & \color{green} 7 & \color{green}{19} \\
 -9 &  -7 &   0 & \color{green}{12} \\
-21 & -19 & -12 &  0
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
You would need to traverse the $N = ((4-1)4/2 = 6$ elements above the diagonal to evaluate your query.

In a real program you would not construct the full matrix but would use two loops for the indices $i$, $j$ with proper parameters and act on the set $A$, to just calculate the $N$ positive differences and not more.

**Update:**

The related problem turns out to find a function, which takes a sequence (a tuple) of times
$$
t = (t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n)
$$
where $t_i < t_j$ for $i < j$ and to split this sequence along gaps $t_{ij} = t_j - t_i \ge 6$.

Using a programming language expressing this would take more room than the description above, depending on the support of that language for organizing and processing data as tuples or lists, a Ruby program would be shorter than a C program.

A mathematical function would be recursive and probably need some helper functions to formulate operations on a tuple.

Comment: Wow, amazing, but scared!! It is possible to formulate an example based on the formula? I need to implement a mysql query to solve this.

Comment: In A = {1, 3, 10, 22} I have 6 positive elements in matrix, but the correct answer would be 3 visits (1 and 3; 10; 22)... or I misunderstood something?

Comment: Sorry for my difficulty in understanding (and I appreciate so much your effort to help), but by given example how would I do to get the desired result of 3 visits? For A = {1, 3, 10, 22} the result would be 3 visits.

Comment: The upper matrix half features all 6 interval lengths which occur. And the five green ones have a length of at least 6. I do not understand why you get only three.

Comment: I will try to explain my real problem: imagine a person visiting a place at different times. I must consider a new visit every 6 hours since the last. In {1, 2, 3} or {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} I have 1 visit. In {1, 2, 3, 10, 11} I have 2 visits. In {1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 22} I have 3 visits and so on...

Comment: It is not clear what you consider a visit and what not.

Comment: A visit is a sequence of values that does not have a gap greater or equal to 6.

Comment: OK. See my update. Providing a piece of code would be rather easy, cranking out a bunch of recursive functions for the same task would have the only benefit to show that it can be specified this way. The question remains what would actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the MAX-GAP problem, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262937/array-maximum-difference-algorithm-that-runs-in-on